# WORD 2019 Crashes When Using Macro on Large Documents

Tags: vba, search, ms-word, crash

I wrote the 1st ever macro.(Windows 10, WORD 2019)
I'm trying to find words that start with a capital letter in Standard style and continue to have Italic style.
Unfortunately, if I search a document using too many letters in the query - the macro closes (after checking, for example, 1.5 pages) or resets the WORD program.

If I reduce the number of words searched - the macro starts to run longer and longer.
With, for example, a search for 1 letter (U) instead of 32 (ABCDEFGHIJKLŁMNOPQRSTUVWXYZĆŚŃŻŹ) - it does not crash the program.

I tried to add

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False at the beginning and 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True at the end of the code but it doesn't help much.
```

---

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim Rng As Range
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
    
    Selection.find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.find.Font
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = False
    End With
    Selection.find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.find
         .Text = "U"
        '.Text = "([ABCDEFGHI])"
        '.Text = "([ABCDEFGHI])"
        '.Text = "([JKLŁMNOP])"
        '.Text = "([QRSTUVWX])"
        '.Text = "([YZĆŚŃŻŹ])"
        '.Text = "([ABCDEFGHIJKLŁMNOPQRSTUVWXYZĆŚŃŻŹ])"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With

    Selection.find.Execute

Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2

Set Rng = Selection.Range

If Rng.Italic = True Then
MsgBox "FIND"
End

If Rng.Italic = False Then
Call Makro1
End If


End If

Call Makro1

End Sub
```

Thanks but your code didn't work. I change the code to:

```
If .Words.Last.Characters(2).Font.Italic = True Then
 .Characters(1).Font.Italic = True
End If
```

.find.Execute
but it only worked sometimes. When I enabled the macro on a longer text, the macro would hang, show error 5941 "collection object not exist" and stop on the line:

If .Words.Last.Characters(2).Font.Italic = True Then
I spent a lot of time before I discovered why. It turns out that the macro crashes because sometimes there is a punctuation mark in the text next to a capital letter, e.g. period comma...etc. e.g A. B; C: D., The code would have to be improved to ignore this. I try add .IgnorePunct = True after .MatchCase = True but didn't help and macro still crashes

I try change code:

.Text = "<[A-Z][!.,;:„”#$%-+=[\[/[//[@[?[![#[$[%[*[([)[&[*[{[}]*>"
Macro fix some errors in text, work longer but still somewhere is an unacceptable sign after a character with a capital letter and the macro crashes.

Add more unwanted signs

.Text = "<[A-Z][!.,;:„”#$%-+=[\[/[//[@[?[![#[$[%[*[([)[&[*[{[}[<[>_|` - …]*>"
and still the macro crashes.

After rewriting the code to show live which words it checks, I was able to understand in part why the macro crashes.
Problem is hard space:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojp5M.jpg) and the comma after digit
if I use normal space instead of hard space - macro work OK.

If change to N = 5, to N = 5 , also work OK.

Another place with STOP working:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFNMp.jpg)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V8yP.jpg)

I don't know what other adjustments to make so that the macro doesn't hang up in these places.

[EDIT]
I don't know too much what I'm doing, but I changed the code to:

```
Sub m1select()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
           With Selection.find
       .Text = "<[A-Za-z0-9][! ^13.^s^t^+^=,;:„”#$%-+=[\[[\][\\[\/[\//[\@[\?[\![\#[\$[\%[\*[\([\)[\&[\*[\{[\}[\<[\>_|` - …-]*>"
           .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
        End With
       With ActiveDocument.Content
         Do While Selection.find.Found
If Selection.Words.Last.Characters(1).Font.Italic = True Or Selection.Words.Last.Characters(2).Font.Italic = True Then
Selection.Font.Italic = True
    End If
 Selection.find.Execute
      Loop
    End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

and it works.  It now corrects all words with partial Italic font not just capitalized.
Admittedly, it does it slowly because I used "Select" , but that way I can see what character the macro hangs on and add it to the exclusion in after the [!
( as all the time is Application.ScreenUpdating = True)
Doesn't work on expressions with a single U e.g.
U *letter* (after correction it should be *U letter*) but I make it myself with another script.

Comment: Do you get the same results when doing that manually in Word? Sounds like a product issue, not VBA.

Comment: I wrote this childish macro precisely because manually using the Find/Replace function cannot be done.
If I turn on Debugging and execute the code by pressing F8 step by step, the macro runs longer. Instead of 1.5 pages it manages to check 7 pages, but then WORD closes or restarts anyway.
It looks as if the buffer that stores the text selection is overflowing...I don't know anymore.
Or simply the macro is badly written.

Answer (score 0):

you're not finishing your code correctly.
When calling a macro from that macro you're creating a loop which never ends. By calling macro1 all the time, the runtime will terminate the Word Application after too many iterations.
You probably don't need to loop (which is a wired loop you created there) through the selection.

The Find-Object provides everything you need. To write all capital letters which are the first ones in a word to italic, when it's not bold or underlined, you could use this, for example:

```
Sub m()
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Text = "<[A-Z]"
        .Style = "Standard"
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Font.Underline = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .Replacement.Font.Italic = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to set the first capital character of a word to italic, when the secnd character is italic too, you have to loop over all possible words:

```
Sub m1()
    With ActiveDocument.Content
        With .Find
            .Text = "<[A-Z]*>"
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .MatchCase = True
            .Execute Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
        End With
        Do While .Find.Found
            If .Words.Last.Characters(2).Font.Italic = True Then .Font.Italic = True
            .Find.Execute
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

You could specify other letters like you did above if you need/want.

If you need more precise selection criteria, you can search them on the help page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en/office/vba/api/word.find

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Your code works and it works very fast.
Unfortunately, it didn't do what I wanted to achieve.
Your code converts the first capital letters in EVERY word. Mine is to fix the style of the first letter to Italic ONLY if there is a Standard style used on it instead of Italic.

Comment: What do you mean with "standard style"? Do you mean the format pattern? Why don't you set the .Style property of your find method to "Standard" and try it again?
P.S.: Edited my post above

Comment: Standard font meaning not "Italic" font.

Comment: I try repalce e.g R*eport* to *Report* U*SA* to *USA* .It's my first ever macro-I don't know much yet.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't really the question you wrote above. But please find an edit in my answer.
there we loop through all found words and trying to find the italic ones

Answer (score 0):

You guided me to the solution.
The problem was calling the macro in a loop using Call.
After adding START: at the beginning (and then the rest of the code) and instead of "Call Macro 1" writing "GoTo START" in two places solved the problem.

Comment: Please don't ever use GoTo or any form of jump points in your code. It's a terrible way of programming.

Comment: Welcome to SO! you said  that "You guided me to the solution", but the day next you said "Thanks but your code didn't work". In that case, delete this [not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185074/463531) and write this as an Edit in your question, or simply as part of your actual answer below.